# How to replace null with 0 in SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I need to replace **null** with **0** in my `SSAS cube`. what is the proper way to achieve that?

This is my current query:

```
SELECT {([Measures].[Employee Age Count])} 
ON COLUMNS, { ([Dim Gender].[Gender Name].[Gender Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dim Age Ranges].[Age Range ID].[Age Range ID].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] }) ON COLUMNS
FROM [People Dashboard]) 
WHERE ( [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] )
```

Result from current query:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `IIF(ISEMPTY...` is pretty standard.

I have also simplified your script by deleting quite a few braces & also moving the logic out of the subselect into a basic `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MEASURE_NONEMPTY] AS 
  IIF(
     ISEMPTY([Measures].[Service Period Count])
     ,0
     ,[Measures].[Service Period Count]
  )
SELECT 
   {[Measures].[MEASURE_NONEMPTY]} ON 0,
       [Dim Gender].[Gender Name].[Gender Name].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim Age Ranges].[Age Range ID].[Age Range ID].ALLMEMBERS  
     ON 1
FROM [People Dashboard]
WHERE [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MEASURE_NONEMPTY] AS COALESCEEMPTY([Measures].[Service Period 
Count], 0)
SELECT {[Measures].[MEASURE_NONEMPTY]} ON COLUMNS, { ([Dim Gender].[Gender Name].[Gender 
Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Age Ranges].[Age Range ID].[Age Range ID].ALLMEMBERS ) 
} ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&
[BOSTON] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [People Dashboard]) WHERE ( [Dim Location].
[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] )
```

I used the code above for my solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested but you can try like below if it works,

```
SELECT {COALESCE (([Measures].[Employee Age Count]),"0") as AgeCount} 
ON COLUMNS, { ([Dim Gender].[Gender Name].[Gender Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dim Age Ranges].[Age Range ID].[Age Range ID].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] }) ON COLUMNS
FROM [People Dashboard]) 
WHERE ( [Dim Location].[Location].[Location Grp Name].&[BOSTON] )
```

Comment: it returns COALESCE function does not exist in Microsoft Sql Server Analysis Services. I tried using COALESCEEMPTY(([Measures].[Employee Age Count]),"0" and got error in: Query (1, 9) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Comment: Let me check it as i told you i am not able to test it currently, but let me check it again